# My character classification model predicts wrong in every case, and I'm not sure if it's because of my code or my data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building a python program to read phone numbers from images, and I want to do that by reading each number one by one and then printing it out at the end. Right now I am trying to just get it working with only one character. Here is the training data I used for the number 3, the rest are very similar(note that I am also including a - and / since some phone numbers contain those characters).

[image: dataset for number 3]

When I try inputting some numbers into the model to predict, it's basically a 0% accuracy and I'm not sure if I did something wrong in my code or is my training data just bad?
Examples of some input:

[image: input data]

And finally here's my code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

VALUES = {
    '0': '0',
    '1': '1',
    '2': '2',
    '3': '3',
    '4': '4',
    '5': '5',
    '6': '6',
    '7': '7',
    '8': '8',
    '9': '9',
    '10': '-',
    '11': '/',
}


def normalize(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image / 255., tf.float32)
    return image, label


train_new_model = True

if train_new_model:
    print("Loading data set...")
    dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'dataset', image_size=(28, 28), color_mode='grayscale', label_mode='int', labels="inferred"
    )
    validation = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'validation', image_size=(28, 28), color_mode='grayscale', label_mode='int', labels="inferred"
    )

    print("Normalizing data...")
    dataset = dataset.map(normalize)

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=len(VALUES), activation=tf.nn.softmax))

    print("Compiling model...")
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    print("Training model...")
    history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=100, validation_data=validation)

    print(history.history.keys())
    # summarize history for accuracy
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    # summarize history for loss
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

    input()

    val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(dataset)
    print("Loss: ", end="")
    print(val_loss)
    print("Accuracy: ", end="")
    print(val_acc)

    print("Saving model...")
    model.save('digits.model')
else:
    # Load the model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('digits.model')

image_number = 1
while os.path.isfile('digits/digit{}.png'.format(image_number)):
    try:
        # Convert image to a flat black and white image, and invert them
        originalImage = cv2.imread('digits/digit{}.png'.format(image_number))
        grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(originalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        (thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        img = 255 - blackAndWhiteImage
        img = np.invert(np.array([img]))

        # Predict and read from solution VALUES
        prediction = model.predict(img)
        solution = np.argmax(prediction)
        print("Predicted character:", end="")
        print(VALUES[str(solution)])

        # Show the image
        plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
        plt.show()

        input()  # Wait for input to continue
    except BaseException as error:
        print('An exception occurred: {}'.format(error))
        print("Error reading image! Proceeding with next image...")
    finally:
        image_number += 1
```

Here's the model loss graph:

[image]

Comment: The training process would be interesting that we could see, if the network is learning properly.

Comment: @Steradiant How exactly can I show you that? Should I upload the model folder or print some things?

Comment: You could show us the output of the training process (I'd also suggest to split the dataset into training and validation data to get proper figures). Or you could simply plot the trining history (e.g. have a look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/)

Comment: @Steradiant Thanks! Added the graph to my post, along with a bit of validation data(only 10 or so images)

Answer (score 1):

One potential issue that stands out to me is that some images in your dataset are inverted. (In your first screenshot, I see some black 3's on a white background, and some white 3's on a black background). I know it would be cool if the model could deal with this discrepancy on its own, but that may not be realistic, at least not without some help. Try pairing down your dataset to be consistent about the way digits look, re-train, and then see how it's performing.

To further diagnose the code, some output would be nice. What happens to the loss as the network trains? Is it blowing up or failing to converge?

Once you've nailed down this issue, you can start thinking about how to deal with a more diverse dataset with both black and white backgrounds. Maybe you could include a pass to detect the "type" on an input image and standardize it (ie turn white-on-black images into black-on-white images, and pass that into the classifier).

Comment: Which one would you recommend? Black digits on white background or the other way around? Going to try that. All my input is going to be white background, but I did this because some of my training data had colors, so I just wanted to remove the colors. `Epoch 200/200
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 8.3423e-05 - accuracy: 1.0000` Here's the final step in training. I will now try to get a picture of the graph with the data a commenter above mentioned.

Comment: I recommend black on white, but I doubt it actually matters. That loss seems suspiciously low to me at first glance.

Comment: Okay, I deleted all inverted images. And I added a few(like 10 or so) images for validation. Now when training my `val_accuracy` starts with 0.1667, then it climbs to 0.25 on Epoch 3, and then it just stays on 0.25 till the end, so it seems like my model isn't actually improving?

Comment: Yeah, 0.25 is not so good. The graph you posted above screams overfitting - the "test" loss (which is really "validate"?) is going up while the training loss is floored. That means the model isn't generalizing well. How much data are you working with?

Comment: After removing the inverted ones, about 20-30 images for every character `Found 262 files belonging to 12 classes`

Comment: Ok, that may be too little data for a model of this size. Maybe try more data or a simpler model? I just tested your code on my system with a subset of the MNIST digits dataset and it worked okay, so I don't think there are any fundamental problems with your code.

Comment: After further testing, I think it might be the way that I am feeding the data to the program to predict.. I also tried downloading the MNIST dataset and my val_accuracy was 96%, with 42k training images and 600 validation images.. Which is superb, but then I tried feeding it my own handwritten symbols and it just kept guessing the same number(and it was always incorrect)...